# How to install qbittorrent in Ubuntu 16.10?

Tags: software-installation, 16.10, qbittorrent, torrent-client

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.10 and unsuccessfully tried installing qbittorrent from Software center as I would do usually till 16.04, but it showed up some error.

Comment: “Some error” can usually be fixed by *some action*. You'll need to provide more detail to receive helpful answers. What is the *exact, verbatim* error message when you try to install qBittorrent? Even better yet, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), run `sudo apt-get install -f qbittorrent` and [edit] your question to include the output of that command.

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (>100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new release of 16.10, I had few problems installing qbittorrent from the Ubuntu Software center as well as from the .tar.gz installation file obtained from original website of qbittorrent. However I got a way to compile it locally in my system, though it showed some warnings, eventually, it happened to be working properly.

First try installing it thorugh this method :

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qbittorrent-team/qbittorrent-stable
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install qbittorrent
```

hopefully everything should be good and QbitTorrent should get installed successfully.
If not then try compiling it from its source files as follows :

- First you must install the required dependencies :

  1. General required dependencies

     `sudo apt-get install libboost-dev libboost-system-dev build-essential`
  2. Qt4 libraries (optional and only if it exists in your distro's repo)

     `sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev`
  3. Qt5 libraries

     `sudo apt-get install qtbase5-dev qttools5-dev-tools`
  4. Python (Run time only dependency, for the search engine)

     `sudo apt-get install python`
  5. Optional Dependencies Geoip Database (For peer country resolution, strongly advised)

     `sudo apt-get install geoip-database`
- Libtorrent : Libtorrent is a library written by Arvid Norberg that qBittorrent depends on. It is necessary to compile and install libtorrent before compiling qBittorrent. If your distro packages at least libtorrent 0.16.19 or 1.0.6 you can install it. Otherwise you'll need to compile it yourself.

  `sudo apt-get install libtorrent-rasterbar-dev`

  If this dowsn't work, you might probably have to compile it too from its source. Find more instructions here " https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/Compiling-qBittorrent-on-Debian-and-Ubuntu "
- Compiling qBittorrent

First, obtain the qBittorrent source code. Either download and extract a .tar archive from [www.qbittorrent.org](http://www.qbittorrent.org/)  or clone this git repo (git clone https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent)  :

1. Extract the files in a folder and open a terminal in that location
2. executre the configure file with this command in the directory containing the extracted files
      `sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr`

   if shows any error, probably try

   `sudo ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-qt4`
3. execute   `make`
4. then      `sudo make install`

Hopefully this should install qbittorrent in your latest Ubuntu 16.10.

For this answer, I would like to thank Github users [Arvid Noberg](https://github.com/arvidn), [Mike Tzou](https://github.com/Chocobo1) and [Diego de las Heras](https://github.com/ngosang) who actively maintain the Github Repo [qbittorrent](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent). The instruction I got from the repo's instructions were deephly helpful.

For any other help, refer the source here : [How to compile qbittorrrent from source](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/Compiling-qBittorrent-on-Debian-and-Ubuntu)